# cyclic inference in Retrofit RxJava nested observables

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

New in rxJava I'm struggling in order to get an Observable by nesting retrofit Observables.
On the code block `.map(userResponse -> {
                                        data.put
                                        final Intent resd = new Intent();
                                        resd.putExtras(data);
                                        return (Intent)resd;
                                    });`

I get a cyclic inference error.
When I try to compile I get a weird message I don't quite understand as :

> Error:(52, 21) error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>   (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
>   Intent cannot be converted to Observable)
>   where R,T are type-variables:
>   R extends Object declared in method flatMap(Func1>)
>   T extends Object declared in class Observable

here is the code:

```
public Observable<Intent> createUser(final String email) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    return mWebservice.clientAuth("myFakeClientId") //returns an Observable<AccessToken>
            .map(clientTokenObject -> {
                String clientToken = clientTokenObject.accessToken;
                Observable<Response<User>> userResponseObservable = mWebservice.createAccount(email);
                Observable<Intent> resultObs =  userResponseObservable
                                .map(userResponse -> {
                                    final Intent resd = new Intent();
                                    resd.putExtras(data);
                                    return (Intent)resd;
                                });
                        return resultObs;
                    });
}
```

;(

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping is wrong. You need something like

```
public Observable<Intent> createUser(final String email) {

    return mWebservice.clientAuth("myFakeClientId") //returns an Observable<AccessToken>
                      .map(clientTokenObject  -> clientTokenObject.accessToken)
                      .flatMap(accessToken -> { mWebservice.createAccount(email).
                                                       .map(userResponse -> {
                                                                final Intent resd = new Intent();
                                                                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                                                                resd.putExtras(data);
                                                                return (Intent)resd;
                                                            })});
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found out the same thing (but it was by chance trying things...) I really don't get the difference between map() ant fatMap() (appart the flattening stuff), thanks for your answer

Comment: Marble diagrams help. Check the [diagram in the documentation for flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).